# How to use Yarn registry as Azure DevOps artifact upstream feed?

Tags: azure-devops, yarnpkg, lerna, azure-artifacts

I have a mono repo in Azure DevOps that contains JavaScript packages. I use lerna for managing packages and yarn as package manager. I'm new to Azure DevOps artifacts and I want to setup yarn to be a upstream feed. I have read [Use npm to store JavaScript packages in Azure DevOps Services or TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-npm?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#feedback) and followed the steps. With `npm` seems everything works fine and after I enter `npm i` in my project I can see packages that sourced `npm` in azure artifact. But if I use yarn nothing happens. Can somebody help me?

Project `.npmrc`:

```
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/_packaging/<OrganizationName>/npm/registry/

always-auth=true
```

Global `.npmrc` in `%HOMEPATH%\.npmrc`

```
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/_packaging/<OrganizationName>/npm/registry/:_authToken=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah
```

I also go to feed settings and add yarn registry as new public upstream source and move it up to be 1st upstream source. but if I enter `yarn install` in my project and then go to Azure artifacts and filter artifacts by source yarn nothing shown.

[image: azure devops feed settings]

`npm ping` with that `.npmrc`s:

```
path\to\project's\package.json>npm ping
npm notice PING https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/_packaging/<OrganizationName>/npm/registry/
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/_packaging/<OrganizationName>/npm/registry/-/ping?write=true
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'ping' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-27T03_20_26_797Z-debug.log
```

`npm ping` in somewhere else:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm ping
npm notice PING https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm notice PONG 1.296ms
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I deleted Yarn cache folder in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Yarn\Cache`and also `yarn.lock` file  and `node_modules` folder in my project root and then reinstalled packages. I think problem was due to `yarn.lock` file. Because in `yarn.lock` file for each package specified registry and because I haven't `package-lock.json` npm works and yarn doesn't.
You can see before I delete `yarn.lock` file and after I reinstall package in image blow:

[image: yarn.lock file changed registry]